# Is it True that Two + Two = 2? If so, what is Ten + Ten and Nine + Nine?

Tags: logical-deduction, knowledge, calculation-puzzle

Given:

SIX + ZERO = 4

TWO + THREE = 15

FIVE + SIX = 88

ONE + TWO = 83

TEN + TWO = 13

If so, is TWO + TWO = 2 correct?

What is TEN + TEN ?    NINE + NINE ?

Hint 1

> NINE + TWO= 23             TEN - TWO  =  11

Comment: Based on well known system..since nobody got it so far, I am going to add couple of equations in the hint. Which will lead to easy solution

Comment: "easy solution" not necessarily. Sometimes the solution to the puzzle seems easier to the OP than it might be in reality.

Comment: True..because of more familiarity..in this case I meant relative to before the hint..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My attempts:

> I thought that SIX + ZERO = 4 $\implies$ S + I + X + Z + E + R + O = 4 ...(i)
>
> Similarly, 2T + 2E + W + O + H + R = 15  ...(ii)
>
>  F + 2I + V + E + S + X = 88             ...(iii)
>
>  2O + N + E + T + W = 83                 ...(iv)
>
>  2T + N + E + O + W = 13                 ...(v)

From (iv) and (v),

> O - T = 70 ...(vi) 
>  I found some more equations like above. But the hints made it even simple.

From the hints,

> TEN - TWO = 11 also we have TEN + TWO = 13
>  On adding, 2(TEN) = 2(T+E+N) = 24 or TEN = 12
>  $$TEN+ TEN= 24$$
>  On Subtracting, 2(TWO) = 2
>  TWO + TWO  = 2 True (asked in the question)
>  So, TWO = 1
>  As, NINE + TWO = 23 $\implies$ NINE = 23 -1 = 22
>  $$NINE + NINE = 22 +22 = 44$$

Verification

> TEN + TWO = 13, we have TEN = 12, TWO = 1, so it holds.
>  ONE + TWO = 83
>  On subtracting, ONE  = 83 - 1 = 82
>  Working on other equations...

Comment: nice answer! @Ak19

Comment: Is it solvable without the hints a.k.a there may be more than one solutions?

Comment: @ athin I don't know, first I tried before the hint was posted, didn't get the solution and left it. The day before yesterday, I saw the hint and tried, it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

From the hint, since we have

> $$\mathrm{TEN} + \mathrm{TWO} = 13$$

and

> $$\mathrm{TEN} - \mathrm{TWO} = 11$$

then it follows that

> $\mathrm{TWO} = 1$, and $\mathrm{TEN} = 12$.

Hence both

> **TWO + TWO = 2** and **TEN + TEN = 24**.

Now since

> $$\mathrm{NINE} + \mathrm{TWO} = 23$$

and we already know

> $\mathrm{TWO}$,

we have

> $\mathrm{NINE} = 22$.

Hence

> **NINE + NINE = 44**.

All the other equations are superfluous.